# Expectation of number of runs until all events have happened?

Tags: probability, expectation

I have a set of devices, $N$ of each, where each device $d_1,d_2,...$ has an associated probability $p_1,p_2,...$ of firing.

I test all devices in one run, and remove those that fire. I then repeat the process, removing at each run any devices that fired.

How can I calculate the expected number of runs to have seen all devices having fired?

For example, say I have 3 each of devices $a,b,c,d$, where respective probabilities of any one firing during a run are $.1, .2, .3, .4$

I do a run, and 2 of the $a$ fire, 1 of the $b$, and all of the $c, d$ fire, leaving me with 1 $a$ and 2 $b$, so I do a new run with just those, and so on until I've seen all of them fire.

I've done a simulation for this, but I'm wondering if there's a clean and direct mathematical way to get the answer.

Comment: Each device fires after a random time $T_k$ geometric with parameter $p_k$ hence $T=\max T_k$ is such that $$P(T\geqslant n)=1-P(\forall k,T_k\leqslant n-1)=1-\prod_k(1-P(T_k\geqslant n))=1-\prod_k(1-q_k^{n-1})$$ with $q_k=1-p_k$ hence $$E(T)=\sum_{n\geqslant1}P(T\geqslant n)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}1-\prod_k(1-q_k^{n}).$$ To get $E(T)$ as a finite sum, consider the subsets $I$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$, then, expanding the products and using the notations $$q_I=\prod_{k\in I}q_k,$$ yields ...

Comment: ...  $$E(T)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\sum_{I\ne\varnothing}(-1)^{|I|+1}q_I^n={}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}\sum_{I\ne\varnothing}\frac{(-1)^{|I|+1}}{1-q_I}.$$ For example, if $N=3$, then $$E(T)=\frac1{p_1}+\frac1{p_2}+\frac1{p_3}-\frac1{1-q_1q_2}-\frac1{1-q_2q_3}-{}{}{}\frac1{1-q_3q_1}+\frac1{1-q_1q_2q_3}.$$

Comment: @Did It may be a stupid question but why $E(T)=\sum_n P(T\geq n)$ and not $\sum_n n P(T=n)$?

Comment: @wece: Those two forms are equivalent. $P(T=k)$ contributes exactly $k$ times (for $1\le n\le k$) in the first form.

Comment: Indeed, equivalently, for every nonnegative integer valued random variable $X$, $$X=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\mathbf 1_{X=n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{X\geqslant n}.$$

Comment: @joriki  ok, sorry it was obvious ... thank you

Comment: @Did ok thank you. (btw why not an answer?)

Comment: For strictly positive discrete (integer-valued) random variables: $\begin{align}\mathsf E(T) ~= & ~\sum_{n>0} n \mathsf P(T=n)\\ =&~\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^n \mathsf P(T=n)\\ =& ~\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty P(T=n)\\ = & ~ \sum_{m=1}^\infty P(T\geq m)\end{align}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Why the repetition? Why the terrible alignment?

Comment: @Did: This is a particularly egregious case of comments that should have been an answer :-)